# How can I limit what types are used for my generic interface?

Tags: c#

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IService<T>
    {
        void AddOrUpdate(T tab);
        bool Available();
```

Can I limit this interface so that it can only be used for certain types?

**What's** the significance of the parameter name **"tab"**. Could this be any sensible name or is there a connection with where the interface is used?

Comment: Sorry should be "tab". It's the name that was given to the parameter. Can it be anything?

Comment: tab is just a name. You can specify any meaningful name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I limit this interface so that it can only be used for certain types?

Yes, you can restrict generic type usage like so:

```
public interface IService<T> where T : IServicableType
```

In this case, T can only be a type that implements (or inherits from, be it a class) `IServicableType`.

> Could this be any sensible name or is there a connection with where the interface is used?

No, the parameter name does not matter. The parameter name of the class's method does not need to reflect the parameter name of the interface. This is because parameter names do not effect a method's signature. Only the signatures must match.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the `where` keyword to limit what types to be used for generic type.

Example:

```
public interface IService<T>where T:IComparable { }
{
        void AddOrUpdate(T tab);
        bool Available();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

The letter 'T' has no significance. Just specifies type or template. You can use any letter.
'tab' is just a name. You can specify any meaningful name.

Answer (score 2):

Look at following article about [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). These constrains are defined using the where keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You can say something like:

```
public interface IService<T> where T : Employee
{
            void AddOrUpdate(T tab);
            bool Available();
}
```